# Nebensatz zu einer "Nominalgruppe"

Tags: sentence-structure, noun, adverb, past-participle, nominalization

Man kann sagen

> bezüglich der erforderlichen Mittel, die für den Neubau aufzubringen sind

Kann man auch entsprechend sagen

> bezüglich der für den Neubau erforderlich aufzubringenden Mittel

*Aufzubringenden* scheint mir sehr fraglich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, das kann man sagen. Allerdings bedeutet der neue Satzteil etwas anderes als der ursprüngliche. Im ursprünglichen Satzteil

> bezüglich der *erforderlichen Mittel*, die für den Neubau aufzubringen sind

ist *erforderlichen* ein Adjektiv, das das Substantiv *Mittel* näher beschreibt. In dem neuen Satzteil

> bezüglich der für den Neubau *erforderlich aufzubringenden* Mittel

ist *erforderlich* hingegen ein Adverb, das das Partizip *aufzubringenden* näher beschreibt. Wenn Sie ein Partizip verwenden, aber die ursprüngliche Bedeutung beibehalten wollen, könnten Sie schreiben:

> bezüglich der für den Neubau aufzubringenden *erforderlichen Mittel*

Answer (score 1):

Ja, das kannst du so sagen. "Aufzubringenden" ist völlig in Ordnung. Die Bezüge zwischen den Satzteilen unterscheiden sich aber ein wenig zwischen deiner ersten und deiner zweiten Variante, und zwar wegen der Reihenfolge der Wörter und weil du das Adverb "erforderlich" benutzt.

Wenn du den Relativsatz einfach nur in eine Partizipialkonstruktion umwandeln möchtest, alle Bezüge aber gleich bleiben sollen, dann wäre das:

> bezüglich der erforderlichen, für den Neubau aufzubringenden Mittel.

(Das Komma ist optional.)

In deiner Variante bezieht sich *für den Neubau* auf *erforderlich* statt auf *aufzubringen*, was in diesem Beispiel vermutlich keinen großen Unterschied macht, aber in anderen Fällen möglicherweise schon.

Wenn du "erforderlich" statt "erforderlichen" benutzt, wird     "erforderlich" zu einem Adverb zu "aufzubringen". Das ist grammatisch korrekt und kann man so machen, es klingt für mich nur etwas ungewöhnlich. Es verändert auch den Sinn noch etwas mehr. Jetzt sind es nicht mehr die *Mittel*, die *erforderlich* sind, sondern jetzt ist das *Aufbringen* der Mittel *erforderlich*. Auch hier ist der Unterschied semantisch ziemlich subtil.

Wenn man es stilistisch betrachtet, ist die Variante mit dem Relativsatz, denke ich, deutlich leichter lesbar. Je nach Kontext, in dem der Satz erscheint, kann man sich auch fragen, was eigentlich der inhaltliche Unterschied zwischen "erforderlich" und "aufzubringen" sein soll. Werden überhaupt beide Verben benötigt? Wenn man den Satz verkürzt zu

> bezüglich der für den Neubau erforderlichen Mittel.

geht inhaltlich vermutlich nichts verloren.

---

Yes, you can say that. "Aufzubringenden" is completely fine. The relations between the parts are shifting a little bit though between your first and your second variant because of your word order and using the adverb "erforderlich".

If you'd just like to convert the relative phrase to a participial phrase while keeping all the relations between part intact, that would be

> bezüglich der erforderlichen, für den Neubau aufzubringenden Mittel.

(The comma is optional.)

In your variant, *für den Neubau* specifies *erforderlich* instead of *aufzubringen*, which probably makes no big difference in this example, but it would in other cases.

If you use "erforderlich" instead of "erforderlichen", you're making  "erforderlich" an adverb dependent on "aufzubringen", which is grammatically correct and actually fine, it just sounds a bit odd/unidiomatic to me. It also shifts the meaning even more. It's not directly the *Mittel* any more that are *erforderlich*, but now the *Aufbringen* of the *Mittel* is *erforderlich*. (Sorry for the language mix). Again, semantically, the difference is quite subtle in this example.